# Magento 2 - Invalid template error after adding custom shipping method and running setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, extensions, shipping, invalid-template

I have added a custom shipping method module to the `app/code` folder and after running `setup:upgrade` I am getting the following error message on the home page:

```
Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'product/widget/content/grid_v16.phtml' in module: 'WeltPixel_OwlCarouselSlider' block's name: 'slider\products_0'
```

I have also run the `cache:flush` and `cache:clean` commands.

Edit: Just to clarify, the Carousel Slider widget that is giving the error has nothing to do with my module that was uploaded. The rest of the site is functioning normally.

Any ideas?

Magento version is 2.2.4

Comment: can you please share your code.

Comment: @AnasMansuri - which files do you need to see?

Comment: something wrong with your module, please check with your layout file.